# i dont know how to declare Cursor and get method at same time and use it Cursor c? what i need too is to return all the names

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cursor

I have class called `unviersityClient` and method name `getallstudent,but how to include them in cursor to get results displayed
this is in mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private TextView tv;
private Button bt;
private Context mycontext;
Cursor c;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mycontext=this.getApplication();




    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //       universityClient.addStudents(mycontext, "christy");
  //   universityClient.addStudents(mycontext, "joe");

            universityClient.getAllStudents(mycontext);
            c.moveToFirst();
           while(!c.isAfterLast()){


               String dir =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                tv.setText("Name : "+dir);
               c.moveToNext();

           }
```

and this is in .java created by json. it's already created the db

```
 public static Cursor getAllStudents(Context c) {
ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();
String[] result_columns = new String[]{
    universityDB.STUDENTS__ID_COLUMN,
    universityDB.STUDENTS_NAME_COLUMN,
    };
String where = null;
String whereArgs[] = null;
String order = null;
Cursor resultCursor = cr.query(university.STUDENTS_URI, result_columns, where, whereArgs, order);
return resultCursor;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you have all the students in a database you can use this to get all the names and then send them to a variable

```
String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Tutores t1 INNER JOIN Tutorados t2 ON t1._id = t2.id_tutor and t1._id = " + ET1.getText().toString().trim();
                    cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);

                    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                C1 = cursor.getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex("_id"));

                                C2 = cursor.getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex("name"));

                                Fin += C1 + "-" + C2  + "\n";

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }                       
                    }
                    cursor.close();
```

Fin is a String and you can get all the names or whatever you want from the columns with the `getColumnIndex("nameOfTheColumn")` and send "Fin" to a textview or something like that

hope that helps!, see ya

Comment: i have json file called students

Comment: json, uh? that's different, why no use the json tag and explain it in the post?

Comment: i'm sorry i can't help you with json, i sayed to include the json tag and information, if someone else can help you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand why you want to put json data in cursor while json parsing is the best way to do the same. If your priority is to bring data somewhere else and fetch one by one using loop, you can use arraylist/hashmap like collection objects. If you have many fields in one json object, you can create a class having those fields and make an arraylist of that having type of class and store data in that. Like this:
1. Fetch single json object at a time, fetch values of fields.
2. create class object by passing those values in constructor.
3. Create arraylist of that class type.
4. put class objects in that arraylist one by one and fetch as well.

```
ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person newPerson = new Person("balvier", "27", "Male");
person.add(newPerson);
Person newPersonAnother = new Person("Adel", "20", "FeMale");
person.add(newPersonAnother);
```